# The standard mechanism to switch GPUs isn't undocumented, is it?

Tags: linux, gpu, documentation, mesa

My laptop is a normal, uninteresting machine with two standard, unmultiplexed GPUs and an ordinary Debian stretch installation. The secondary GPU (a Radeon) is usually powered down but I can activate and use it by (for example) `DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears`. Mesa's source file *src/loader/loader.c* manages it.

Is `DRI_PRIME` undocumented?

I wish to read the documentation but cannot find it. Oddly, it isn't [here.](https://www.mesa3d.org/envvars.html) Moreover, Google [cannot locate it.](https://www.google.com/search?q=mesa%20DRI_PRIME%20site%3Amesa3d.org) If you know where the documentation is, would you tell?

Switching GPUs is a fairly important system function. One would think that the mechanism that does it would be thoroughly documented, but all I can find are a few oblique changelog entries and some online lore like [this.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME)

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

You won't need Debian to answer my question. Any Linux should do.

In case a reader who wishes to start to learn about GPU switching stumbles in here, he can try `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` and then read *html/newstyle/gpu/vga-switcheroo.html* in the Linux kernel source. Also, `man 8 lspci`. It took me two hours to figure out that much, so I mention it here to save the reader time.

Meanwhile, where is the proper documentation of Mesa environment variables like `DRI_PRIME`, please?

Comment: [See Here](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/nouveau/Optimus/)

Comment: @RubberStamp: Aha! Excellent. That is what I wanted. If you have time to make your comment an *answer,* then I would like to upvote it.

Comment: That link isn't the full story. It appears to be possible to specify exactly which GPU you want to use via `DRI_PRIME=pci-0000_00_02_0` or similar which isn't mentioned on the FDO wiki...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote up some notes at https://robots.org.uk/LinuxMultiGPUDeviceSelection - these are not complete but could be used as the basis for a more complete answer if someone wants to write one. :)